What conversion settings need to be specified in ffmpeg in order to get a video with such data in the output?
Here is the information that ffmpeg gives about the video stream:
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.13.100
  Duration: 00:03:08.02, start: 0.003000, bitrate: 48283 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 47988 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 16k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 293 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler

MediaInfo:
General
Complete name                  : C:\Users\kinar\Downloads\241103.mp4
Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media
Codec ID                       : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
File size                      : 1.28 GiB
Duration                       : 3 min 48 s
Overall bit rate               : 48.2 Mb/s
Writing application            : Lavf60.13.100

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : HEVC
Format/Info                    : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                 : Main 10@L5.1@High
Codec ID                       : hev1
Codec ID/Info                  : High Efficiency Video Coding
Duration                       : 3 min 48 s
Source duration                : 3 min 47 s
Bit rate                       : 48.0 Mb/s
Width                          : 3 840 pixels
Height                         : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Variable
Frame rate                     : 60.000 FPS
Minimum frame rate             : 58.824 FPS
Maximum frame rate             : 62.500 FPS
Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.096
Stream size                    : 1.27 GiB (99%)
Source stream size             : 1.27 GiB (99%)
Color range                    : Limited
Color primaries                : BT.709
Transfer characteristics       : BT.709
Matrix coefficients            : BT.709
mdhd_Duration                  : 227383
Codec configuration box        : hvcC

Audio
ID                             : 2
Format                         : AAC LC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                       : mp4a-40-2
Duration                       : 3 min 48 s
Bit rate mode                  : Constant
Bit rate                       : 304 kb/s
Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
Channel layout                 : L R
Sampling rate                  : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                     : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode               : Lossy
Stream size                    : 8.25 MiB (1%)
Title                          : Track1
Default                        : Yes
Alternate group                : 1 

I have a video that needs to be converted with such output data. The sound should remain unchanged. What code do I need to write to convert a video with this kind of output? And what version of ffmpeg is needed for this?

I am not able to tell what you mean by "such data" or "such output data". can you please clarify?

I have another video, I need to convert it to get this result in MediaInfo

It would help to see the MediaInfo output of the file you want to convert. This will determine such things as if the resolution, pixel format, or frame rate need to be converted.

Format                         : MPEG-4
Format profile                 : Base Media
Codec ID                       : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                      : 2.03 GiB
Duration                       : 3 min 29 s
Overall bit rate               : 83.3 Mb/s
Writing application            : Bandicut 2023 v3.7.0.762 / Cutter / HS

Video
ID                             : 1
Format                         : AVC
Format/Info                    : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                 : High@L5.2
Format settings                : CABAC / 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC         : Yes
Format settings, Reference fra : 3 frames
Format settings, GOP           : M=1, N=12
Codec ID                       : avc1
Codec ID/Info                  : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                       : 3 min 29 s

Bit rate                       : 82.9 Mb/s
Width                          : 3 840 pixels
Height                         : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 16:9
Frame rate mode                : Variable
Frame rate                     : 60.000 FPS
Minimum frame rate             : 30.000 FPS
Maximum frame rate             : 15 360.000 FPS
Original frame rate            : 59.940 (60000/1001) FPS

Color space                    : YUV
Chroma subsampling             : 4:2:0
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Scan type                      : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 0.167
Stream size                    : 2.02 GiB (100%)
Codec configuration box        : avcC

rather than spam the comments, why not put which metadata is important into the question - clearly the mediainfo you have shown is for a particular file, so not ALL of it is going to be exactly what you want

not knowing your metadata, when i convert a gopro video and wish to retain the gyro data, i use -movflags use_metadata_tags -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:3 -tag:2 gpmd

Based on the media info of your source and destination files, everything matches up except for the codec, which needs to be converted to HEVC.
Use the following ffmpeg command to convert your video to HEVC while keeping the auto track and everything else the same:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v libx265 -preset slow output.mp4
This command will copy the audio track without re-encoding it and use the libx265 encoder to encode the video into the HEVC format. The -preset slow option will produce the highest quality output, but it will take longer to process.
Note: If you have a GPU that supports hardware acceleration for HEVC encoding (e.g., NVIDIA or AMD GPUs), you can add the appropriate hardware acceleration options to the ffmpeg command. However, the specific options will vary depending on your GPU and ffmpeg version.
This command should work with any version of ffmpeg.

I would like to know how to add Color primaries : BT.709
Transfer characteristics: BT.709
Matrix coefficients : BT.709 in MediaInfo. And use ffmpeg Writing application version: Lavf60.13.100

Libavformat (Lavf60.13.100) is a library used by FFMPEG for dealing with various media container formats. Its main two purposes are demuxing - i.e. splitting a media file into component streams, and the reverse process of muxing - writing supplied data in a specified container format.

Use the following options to use BT.709: -colorspace:v "bt709" -color_primaries:v "bt709" -color_trc:v "bt709" -color_range:v "tv"

CyberSimon, Thanks for your help.

Sorry, one more question, how to do it:
Frame rate mode : Variable
Frame rate: 60.000 FPS
Minimum frame rate: 58.824 FPS
Maximum frame rate: 62.500 FPS

Changing frame rate mode can get very complicated. You can specify the mode using the -fps_mode option: -fps_mode vfr Documentation. Converting from constant frame rate to variable frame rate is best done with the fps filter Documentation. It is usually best to leave the frame rate the same as the source unless you have a specific use case which requires a change.
